# Button frame change at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a subclass of `UIButton`:

```
class ColorButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

In interface builder, I set the button with 4 constraints: `width = 100, height = 100, centerX, centerY`.
The button disappears when I run my code on the simulator. However, if it set

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 50
```

it works. I cannot figure it out. If anybody understand this problem, please tell me.

Comment: what is your frame.size.width in awakeNIb method ?

Comment: frame.size.width return 1000 when it print it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in `awakeFromNib` first line:

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Code:

```
class ColorButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: or put them in viewDidLayoutSubviews!

Comment: this worse, because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called many times

Comment: layoutIfNeeded is ironically not needed in awakeFromNib.

Comment: it's needed for get right frame for `self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2`

Comment: @Igor, sorry but that's not true. See my answer, you can test it yourself creating a fresh project in under 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine in a fresh project so I suspect the problem is somewhere else. You forgot to call `super.awakeFromNib()` though. From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib):

> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent
>   classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they
>   require. Although the default implementation of this method does
>   nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations. You may
>   call the super implementation at any point during your own
>   awakeFromNib method.

[image]